# PreferenceActivity Localization

Tags: android, localization, preferenceactivity

am working in a multi language Alarm android application with :

- 1 xml file [alarm_settings.xml]
- 2 string.xml files [English & arabic]

[image: project files]

The problem is that the localization  is not working in the right way, below you can find 4 images 2 for my application and 2 for the device's Settings

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

When you look at these 4 images you can find that in my application the localization works only for the text not for the alignment of views , but you can find in the device's settings that the localization works for both of them - text , views - .

So is it a special case for the device's settings views or i can make my views to be localized like the Device's settings ?!

.java File :

public class MainActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.alarm_settings);
}
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the Solution of the problem at [Android Developers Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html)

in my case it it was to add

```
android:supportsRtl="true"
```

to the element

```
application
```

in

```
 manifest file.
```

Comment: Yahia, can you post the full content of alarm_settings.xml ? I'm trying to achieve the same, made sure that manifest is set properly but still nothing changed.

Comment: this feature is available for android 4.2 only , it's not about the xml file but the manifest